# converting correlated oracle subquery to single query

Tags: oracle, correlated-subquery

Hi I have two tables EMP and Dept( data as normal emp and dept tables of oracle)
I want to find the number of employees earning more than the avg(sal) of their own dept without use of correlated subquery. I wrote the query as below

```
SELECT * from emp e JOIN
   (SELECT avg(sal) avgsal,deptno
          FROM emp group by deptno )avgsal_tab
 on e.sal > avgsal_tab.avgsal where e.deptno =avgsal_tab.deptno
 order by e.deptno
```

This gets me the output but how can I rewrite this with a single query without inline query as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [analytic window functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056):

```sql
SELECT *
from (
  SELECT 
    e.*
    ,avg(sal)over(partition by deptno) avgsal
  from emp e
)
where avgsal>sal
```